# Entity framework navigation properties not included in web api json content

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, json.net

I how the two entities:

```
public partial class Item
{
    public FeedItem()
    {
        this.Votes = new List<Vote>();
    }

    public long ItemId { get; set; }
    public long UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserComment { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Vote> Votes { get; set; }
}

public partial class User
    {
        public User()
        {
            this.FeedItems = new List<FeedItem>();
            this.Votes = new List<Vote>();
        }

        public long Id { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Item> Items { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Vote> Votes { get; set; }
    }
```

On the other side of the of the Http request I see nulls for the `User` property and `Votes` is always an empty collection. I have been playing around all day with `Newtonsoft.Json` attributes like `JsonIgnore` and such and I'm not getting anywhere.

Can this be done or to I need to make a change to my object model in order to transport it via web api?

Comment: Are you using "includes" to make sure the related data is loaded? Have you looked at the executed SQL?

Comment: @TGnat - Well I didn't think to look at the SQL, since I disabled lazy loading, I assumed it would just go ahead and get everything, no?

Comment: And make items and votes IEnumerable<>

Comment: @TGnat - Why IEnumerable?

Comment: Are you using code-first or database-first as your EF dev approach? In code-first, if your collection is decorated with `virtual`, then it's a **lazy loading** collection - just remove the `virtual` to turn that off

Comment: @Elad Lachmi. I initially use List<> for collection properties and they didn't serialize. When I switched to IEnumerable<> it did. I don't have the technical reasons...

Comment: @EladLachmi Turning off lazy loading does just that, EF will not lazy load your navigation properties on demand. It doesn't mean it'll now load them by default. You still have to use eager loading to make sure they are loaded (for example, use `.Include()` in your query).

Comment: @TGnat EF wants at least `ICollection` because it needs an interface it can `Add` to. Elad, turning off lazy loading of the context when serializing is sensible, but the opposite of lazy loading is "no loading, unless" - unless you eagerly load, e.g. by `Include`.

Comment: It's probably important to note that I don't send my entities through web api. I project my entities into model objects that more accurately reflects what the client/service needs.

Comment: @EladLachmi OK, that's even more sensible, but still you can either allow lazy loading *or* (better) make sure that eager loading occurs. Automatic eager loading does not exist.